# I can't understand a piece of code

Tags: javascript, math, random

I'm facing problems understanding a simple notion. Below the code:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 7, 9, 12, 5, 4, 6];
var randomArr = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
console.clear();
console.log(randomArr);
```

What i don't understand from this, is why `Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)` returns a random number each time while `Math.floor(Math.random())` always returns `0` ? From my understanding, `Math.floor(Math.random())` will always return `0` since he generated a value between `0` and `1` (`1` not included), so shouldn't `Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)` always return `8` in my case?

This is what i don't understand at the moment and can't find anything on this matter.

Thanks.

Comment: Math.Floor returns the lower value of the inserted number, Math.random gives a number between 0 and 1 so it will always be lowered to 0.

Comment: Do you know what `Math.random` does? Do you know what `Math.floor` does? Start there, find out which behaviour you don't understand, and (if necessary) ask a more specific question.

Comment: do `var a = Math.random(); console.log( a, a*8, Math.floor(a*8) );` and maybe it becomes more clear.

Comment: No, beacause Math.random() generated a value between 0 and 1, which times 8 will return a number between 0 and 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number. In other words it rounds a number down to the closest integer.

In your code `Math.random()*arr.length` could return a real number as `Math.random` might return .3 and the array length is 8, so instead of the random array element being 2.4, you'll get 2, which makes way more sense if you want to be able to pick the index of an array element. If `Math.random()` returned .5, then you'd get an interger, but the odds are that you wouldn't get an integer in most cases.

Breaking `Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)` down:

- `arr.length` is 8
- `Math.random()` returns a value from 0 up to but not including 1.
- `Math.floor` rounds the result of 8 times `Math.floor` down
- Example using `.3` as the value returned from `Math.random()`:
   `Math.floor( .3 * 8)`
  `Math.floor(2.4)`
  `2`

So given the code `Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)` you'll end up with an integer from  zero to seven, any of which could then be used to select an item in your `arr` array like `arr[randomArr].`